# Running a jar2exe file as jar from command line

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, runtime-error

I am trying to run the NetBeans exe without having a JDK installed to the system, however, I have the 1.8 JDK unzipped to a flash drive. When trying to run the NetBeans exe as a normal jar file using

```
E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javaw.exe -jar E:\Java\NetBeans\bin\netbeans64.exe
```

it says that the jar file is corrupt or invalid. To my knowledge, the exes made from jar files are just jars wrapped to an exe, so I have no idea why it wouldn't work this way.

Comment: EXE files cannot be run using javaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXE files cannot be ran using `java -jar` or `javaw -jar` command only JAR files can be execute like that.

If you want to use mention JDK that netbeans runs on use `netbeans.exe --jdkhome <jdk home>`

In your case the command will be

```
E:\Java\NetBeans\bin\netbeans64.exe --jdkhome "E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_60"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think to look up how to set it within NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans uses Java environment to initiate its installation. Exe and jar are two different files you cannot run exe file via `javaw.exe -jar`